# Isomorphisms between normal subgroups and their quotients

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

Let $G$ and $G'$ be two groups, $f:G \to G'$ a surjective morphism, $H'$ normal subgroup of $G'$ and $H = f^{-1}(H')$.

How to show these isomorphisms ?
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\frac{G'}{H'} @>\sim>> \frac{G}{H} @>\sim>> \frac{G \over \ker{f}}{H \over \ker{f}}
\end{CD}

But before may I need to find what is the third quotient ? And is it possible to show the existence generally or I have to show that a specific morphism is bijective ? Clearly it seem obvious by the hypothesis that a bijection exist between $H$ and $H'$ but after I don't know what to do.

Comment: The second isomorphism is one of the Isomorphism Theorems. The first follows from the first isomorphism theorem by considering the compositum $G\to G'\to *G'/H'$.

Comment: Title: I know what a normal subgroup is. But what is a normal group?

Comment: Or you could do it by hand, if you can be careful enough about what is what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In algebra, a no-brainer that works more than often is to throw the most natural attempt of a map, and then check that it is well defined.

eg for the isomorphism $G/H \cong G'/H'$ :
For $g\in G$, define $\varphi(g + H) := f(g) + H'$.

> $\varphi$ is a well defined map $G/H \mapsto G'/H'$

*$\varphi$ is well defined :* We first have to show that the value of $\varphi(g + H)$ doesn't depend on the choice of $g$, so consider $g'$ such that $g + H = g' + H'$, ie $g-g' \in H$.
One has $$\varphi(g + H) - \varphi(g' + H) = (f(g) + H') - (f(g') + H') = f(g-g') + H'$$
But $g-g' \in H$, hence $f(g-g') \in H'$, and we get $\varphi(g + H) - \varphi(g' + H) = 0$. Hence, $\boxed{\varphi(g + H) = \varphi(g' + H)}$.

Clearly, $\varphi$ is a surjective homomorphism. Let's show that it is also injective (and hence an isomorphism) :

Consider $g \in G$ such that $\varphi(g + H) = H'$. Then we have $f(g) + H' = H'$ hence
$f(g) \in H'$ hence $g \in H$. The only preimage of $0_{G'/H'}$ is $0_{G/H}$ : $\varphi$ is injective.